# Node.js filesystem save file error 56 EROFS while saving every 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I am running node.js on raspbian and trying to save/update a file every 2/3 seconds using the following code:

```
var saveFileSaving = false;

function loop() {
    mainLoop = setTimeout(function() {
        // update data

        saveSaveFile(data, function() {
            //console.log("Saved data to file");
            loop();
        });
    }, 1500);
}

function saveSaveFile(data, callback) {
    if(!saveFileSaving) {
        saveFileSaving = true;
        var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'save.json'));

        wstream.on('finish', function () {
            saveFileSaving = false;
            callback(data);
        });

        wstream.on('error', function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            saveFileSaving = false;
            wstream.end();
            callback(null);
        });

        wstream.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        wstream.end();
    } else {
        callback(null);
    }
}
```

When I run this it works fine for an hour then starts spitting out:

```
[25/May/2016 11:3:4 am]  { [Error: EROFS, open '<path to file>']
  errno: 56,
  code: 'EROFS',
  path: '<path to file>' }
```

I have tried jsonfile plugin which also sends out a similiar write error after an hour.

I have tried both fileSystem.writeFile and fileSystem.writeFileSync both give the same error after an hour.

I was thinking it had to do with the handler not being let go before a new save occurs which is why I started using the **saveFileSaving** flag.

Resetting the system via hard reset fixes the issue (soft reset does not work as the system seems to be locked up).

Any suggestions guys? I have searched the web and so only found one other question slightly similar from 4 years ago which was left in limbo.

Note: I am using the callback function from the code to continue with the main loop.

Comment: Read Only File System?

Comment: I believe something happens during saving that messes with the mounted drive and somehow changes the mounted drive to read only. Which kind of makes sense since a hard reset fixes the issue. But what could be causing that change during file save.

Comment: there is a flag in mounting called something like remount-ro on error, may be check fstab if there is? or just run mount command without any parameters to get the list･

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by unlinking the file and saving the file every time I save while it is not pretty it works and shouldn't cause too much overhead.

I also added a backup solution which saves a backup every 5 minutes in case the save file has issues.

Thank you for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my ideas:

1) Check free space when this problem happens by typing in terminal:

```
df -h
```

2) Also check if file is editable when problem occurs. with nano or vim and etc.

3) Your code too complicated for simply scheduling data manipulation and writing it to file. Because of even Your file will be busy (saveFileSaving) You will lose data until next iteration, try to use that code:

```
var 
  async = require('async'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path');

async.forever(function(next) {
  // some data manipulation

  try {
    fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'save.json'), JSON.stringify(data));
  }
  catch(ex) {
    console.error('Error writing data to file:', ex);
  }

  setTimeout(next, 2000);
});
```

4) How about keeping file descriptor open?

```
var 
  async = require('async'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path');

var file = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'save.json'));

async.forever(function(next) {
  // some data manipulation

  file.write(JSON.stringify(data));
  setTimeout(next, 2000);
});

var handleSignal = function (exc) {
  // close file
  file.end();

  if(exc) {
    console.log('STOPPING PROCESS BECAUSE OF:', exc);
  }
  process.exit(-1);
}

process.on('uncaughtException', handleSignal);
process.on('SIGHUP', handleSignal);
```

5) hardware or software problems (maybe because of OS drivers) with raspberry's storage controller.

Comment: I will check space next time it occurs but the file is 3kb and will always be under 10kb

Comment: Hey mate, After running the app and getting the same problem I tried to run the advised commands and I couldn't the terminal just hangs and does nothing. The only command that actually worked was cd.

I was intrigued by your idea but would that just not append the data to the file constantly? I am looking to replace the file every time I write.

Comment: About replacing: example from (3). About problem: 2 reasons: a. hardware problem, b. no free space, maybe because of swap, or maybe log files...

Comment: I will give (3) a try next, free space shouldn't be an issue as I am only using 15% of 32gb.

Any other ways I can confirm a hardware problem?

Comment: Try to write file to other place, external HDD, or attach dropbox